# hide a specific sheet/tab from shared contacts "editors"

Tags: google-sheets

I want to share a spreadsheet with 4 users.
is there any way to hide all sheets from 3 users and only share a specific sheet/tab with them while the other editor and owner can view all the tabs?

[image: I want to show the only sheet1 and new form to editors accept 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is a way it requires a script which means that in order to hide sheets from those 3 users, those 3 users will need to "install" the script on their google accounts, eg. if they don't then all sheets are visible for them.

maybe a better way is to set up a separate spreadsheet and use `IMPORTRANGE` just for those 3 users

also, note that hidden sheets can be easily unhidden (they are still visible/viewable)

Comment: I can access those accounts and install Scripts on those accounts as well.
for your second option. if I use IMPORTRANGE and share with those users they will not be able to update the sheet. this is the problem.

Comment: here is the scenario: 1 user is me (the IT accounting guy), 2nd user is manager, 3rd and 4rth users are the field guys. Users 1 and 2 need to see all the taps of reports, user 3 and 4 only need 2 tabs of the sheet to enter real-time data.

Comment: @AliAhmed see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812972/5632629 tho I would still recon to do this with multiple spreadsheets and importranges

Comment: If i make a copy of my original spreadsheet and on the copied sheet I use IMPORTRANGE, will it automatically populate my dashboard and other things like the original one. then I will remove the tabs which I want to hide from the original spreadsheet and share the copied sheet with manager so he can view all the reports?

Comment: Thank you, one more thing. let say I have a button/checkbox in column A and and a alphanumeric value in column D. also in spreadsheet there is another sheet "NEW FORM" is there any way if I click or check the checkbox it automatically copy the value  of column A to Cell B1 in the other sheet?

Comment: also script needed for that. see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126083/186471

Comment: I am not scrips much. but i wrote a small script to test which copies from cell A1 value to C5 and from C5 I used =Query to fill my entire form with the information associated with the value of C5. but the thing bothering me. what's next? currently, I need to go to scrips and puch the play button to let it work. how do I set the scrip play on a button? and do I need to write script for each cell? i am stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228143/discussion-between-ali-ahmed-and-player0).